# Does this word need "the"?

Tags: definite-article

I wrote this sentence

> In some cases,such as surfing **the articles of an
>   encyclopedia** or when archiving a news article for ofﬂine reading,
>   it is convenient to get rid of such irrelevant fragments

Do I need "the" before "articles"? Actually I am confused about using "the" in of-phrases, as most the time I have seen them with "the".

Answer (score 1):

If you feel it necessary to include "of an encyclopedia" I would keep it, although this is not essential simply a stylistic choice.
Preferably I would simplify the sentence to something like:

> In some cases,such as surfing encyclopedia articles or when archiving a news article for ofﬂine reading, it is convenient to get rid of such irrelevant fragments.

Or

> Sometimes, like when surfing or archiving articles, it is convenient to get rid of irrelevant fragments.